# How to achieve glossy look in android

Tags: android, android-layout

One of the applications in my mobile has this glossy and transparent look(refer the snapshot below), which is quite beautiful. Just want to know how I can achieve this.

[image]

I am developing an application for myself and want to implement similar kind of GUI. Although I can create a layout, I am still not good in creating beautiful icons like the one shown above. Any information (or) a link to icon development related tutorials should also be quite helpful. Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are just PNG images with transparency and glossy effect... it almost has nothing to do with programming. Just find a good designer and tell him/her to do a 9patch image like that.

By the way... background buttons, in that case should have the border only. The icon and text can be then added easily.

Answer (score 1):

You have to combine multiple techniques. You can use Button where the background will be defined with a nine-patch image, with rounded corners. Then you can use android:drawableLeft parameter of the Button, to define the icon it will have.

As also Cristian suggests, this is not hard to implement. You need a good designer and get to know the basic techniques like 9patch png images, transparency and basic layout definitions. Good luck